# Unable to upgrade current 32GB SSD on Dell XPS 15 9550

Tags: ssd, raid, ahci, xps

I have a Dell XPS 15 9550 with a 1000GB HDD and 32GB SSD and want to upgrade the SSD which is currently only used for cache (from what I know).

I bought the Samsung 970 Pro NVM m.2 SSD. I plugged it in where the 32GB SSD used to be but Windows doesn`t recognise it. The Device Manager recognises it but I can't use it.

I think I need AHCI mode in the BIOS instead of the current RAID one, but I've heard there can be problems with just switching it.

I wanted to just use Samsung Data Migration to copy the OS from the HDD to the SSD. Now is this even possible or sensible with my hardware set up? Can I mabye just change from RAID to AHCI or do I need to install Windows new on the SSD?

Answer (score 0):

> I think I need AHCI mode in the bios instead of the current raid on.

In order to use the Samsung Pro 950 NVMe drive, you do indeed have to switch from RAID to AHCI, but that will likely force you to reinstall Windows to accomplish that.  While it is possible to go from RAID to AHCI without reinstalling Windows, it involves installing the AHCI drivers, before you make the switch.

[image]

Source: [Upgraded XPS 15 9550 to Samsung 950 Pro SSD, getting slow performance](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/upgraded-xps-15-9550-to-samsung-950-pro-ssd-getting-slow-performance.785356/)

> Now is this even possible or sensible with my hardware set up?

Your hardware does indeed support NVMe SSDs.

[image]

Source: [Dell](https://twitter.com/Dell/status/653574596323639297)

Comment: The discussion thread as a possible course of action, on how to avoid having to reinstall Windows, since I cannot confirm the accuracy I will only refer to it in a comment.  You should have all proper backups before you attempt to do anything with your system.  **I will not take responsibility if something goes wrong.**  Use those steps at your own discretion.